# Rspec Error.(Couldn't find Asking with)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This below is spec/controllers/askings_controller_spec.rb.

```
   require 'rails_helper'

    RSpec.describe AskingsController, type: :controller do
     describe 'Get #show' do
      before do 
          @asking=create(:asking)
          get :show , id: @asking.id
      end
      it 'should render show' do
          expect(response).to render_template(:show)
      end
      it 'should Undertaking new' do
          expect(assigns(:undertaking)).to be_a_new(Undertaking)
      end
      it 'should response status 200' do
          expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      end
     end
    end
```

And rspec result is below.

```
     1) AskingsController Get #show should render show
       Failure/Error: @asking=Asking.find(id: params[:id]) 
       ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Asking with 'id'={:id=>"2"}
    2) AskingsController Get #show should Undertaking new
       Failure/Error: @asking=Asking.find(id: params[:id])     
       ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Asking with 'id'={:id=>"2"}
   3) AskingsController Get #show should response status 200
      Failure/Error: @asking=create(:asking)    
      ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
      mailaddress exists.(<- I translate Japanese error.)
```

Why do I have this eeror?
I think that how to use 'create' is incorrect.
Please tell me the solution.

Comment: You may pass wrong params. Try `get :show , {  { id: @asking.id } }`

Comment: Thank you for your comment!Sorry, I tried your solution , but I have still the same error.

Comment: Okay, can you try this? `get :show , @asking.id`

Comment: 1) AskingsController Get #show should render show
     Failure/Error: get :show , @asking.id
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `key?' for 2:Fixnum

Comment: I have this error...

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Comment: Sure!class AskingsController < ApplicationController     def show
        @asking=Asking.find(id: params[:id])
        @undertaking=Undertaking.new
        @undertakings=@asking.undertakings.all
    end  end

Comment: Oh, when I changed find to find_by , I didn't have the error! But I can't understand why... Sorry , If you can understand , please tell me.

Comment: Sorry , I understand!! Thank you for your all advise so much!

Comment: I see, `Asking.find(id: params[:id]) ` should be `Asking.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: You can either use `@asking = Asking.find_by(id: params[:id])` or `@asking = Asking.find(params[:id])` but not `@asking=Asking.find(id: params[:id])`